# This Application only runs under WinPE or WinRE while exploring in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, explorer

I am facing this issue whenever i try to use **"show in explorer"** in Android Studio. Every time i try to locate my generated apk or whether try to see my folders in project i get this error *"This Application only runs under WinPE or WinRE"**. Can anyone help me how to fix this. I have Windows 10 Installed and Android Studio version is latest as well. Somebody help me please to fix this error.
Regards
Here is link to Screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X646A.png

Comment: even the `explorer` command doesn't work.i couldn't find any solution for this.
but `start.` command work properly
Device: 
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version: 10.0.18363 Build 18363
AndroidStudio 3.6.3

Answer (score 6):

think i found the solution.
i don't know is it ok to do this, but it worked for me.

so, you have two explorer.exe in your windows
one in `C:\Windows\System32` and the other in `C:\Windows`.

when you want to open the first one it shows

> This Application only runs under WinPE or WinRE.

error.
but second one is ok and work properly.

so i just copy `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32` and replace it.

> **Note** that it's better to keep the original file somewhere in case it cause a problem.

and now it works fine.

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm told it's the Common Item Dialog, not explorer that opens up your browser. So the solution posted by ahmadreza moodi did not help me while solving this issue.

This error appears in most programs that you try to browse files not only Android Studio, but it will also happen even if you try to open a folder when using cmd.

What helped me is only a Windows Repair Install, but it only lasted a few days before the error was back. I currently have no idea how to solve it permanently.